# Optimal grid clustering

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

First, the 1D case. Given an array of N numbers, cut it into n chunks so that the sum of the squared distance of every element to its chunk average is minimized. For instance, if asked to cut [0.1,0.3,2,1.2,1.3] into three pieces, an optimal solution is [[0.1,0.3],[2],[1.2,1.3]].

With dynamic programming this can easily be solved this in O(N * n)

Now the 2D case. We're given an (N,M) matrix, and we want to cut it in n*m chunks. The solution should look like an irregularly spaced grid - it's a set of n horizontal cuts and m vertical cuts.

This seems trickier. One can dynamically find the optimal vertical cuts by holding the horizontal cuts fixed, but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Enumerating all possible horizontal cuts O(C(M,m)) is intractable.

Is there a way to do this in polynomial time?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like the NP-Hard problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering so I don't think there exists a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: If you can show that an instance of k-means can be transformed into an instance of this problem, then sure. Otherwise, small differences like these can have a huge impact on complexity.